# How is the last rite of a Witcher conducted?

Tags: the-witcher

If a Witcher dies how are his last rites done? Are they buried or cremated?

Comment: Typically when a Witcher dies, they get eaten by whatever killed them

Comment: The answer for the show was shown in the the second season. Have you seen it yet?

Comment: I’m not too familiar with the games but I think this varies depending on the canon. Are you asking across all 3 or one specific one?

Comment: I am asking about the books.

Comment: Then it's just what Valorum said. Witchers don't die from old age. Whatever or whoever kills them does what they want.

Comment: We don't really know. The only witcher who dies during the books/canon die in a big battle and supposedly gets buried in a mass grave along with all the other fallen in that battle and his body wasn't returned to the Witcher School. There are funeral rites both in the show and in the games - and they are different - but neither is canon.